# AVR programmer power supply (ISP ATMEGA16 ATmega32 Minimum Board)

Tags: power-supply, avr, atmega, programmer, isp

In description of an AVR programmer, it is talked about everything except for the input voltage and how to turn it on.

How much voltage should I apply to it?

Somewhere it has mentioned "DC-005 Power Block" but I dont think it means 5 volts.

Other sellers also have not mentioned.

Here are the description from the seller:

[image]

> ```
> 100% brand new and high quality
> Quantity:1pc
> Weight:46 g
> Color: as picture show
> Size:88mmx38mm/3.47"x1.49"(inch) (approx)
> Product Features:
> 1. 32 I/O pin all the leads.
> 2. Classic ATmega16 minimum system, eliminating the hassle of soldering.
> 3. Crystal: The socket hole welding facilitate the buyer to replace the crystal, 8M crystal.
> 4. Support chips: ATmega16/ATmega32 and chip which pin-compatible. 
> 5. Power supply: power adapter or external expansion pin power supply (not support ISP download interface power supply)
> 6. DC-005 Power Block (supporting the transposon is 5.5*2.1mm).
> 7. Expand outside 4 channel VCC, GND.
> 8. Reset: Power-on reset and reset button.
> 9. Power LED (D1) and the program run indicator (D2).
> 10. Standard ISP download interface.
>
> Note: This minimum system development board without AVR chip, you need purchase for chip in additional!!!!
> ```

Comment: Why don't you ask the supplier?

Comment: You _do_ realize that this is not a programmer, right? It is just a breakout board with different connectors.

Comment: The usbasp plugs into this i havent used it but it supports a bunch of atmel chips

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be posted to the supplier of this board.  If he doesn't provide adequate documentation, that's not our problem.  EE.SE is not his volunteer technical support.  (On top of that, this thread attracts too much low quality answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an AVR programmer, although it has an ISP connector where you can attach it. If you need an AVR programmer then search for something like [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/).

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a regulator on the board, it must be supplied with a voltage compatible with the MCU and programmer. 5V is usually safe while programming, but you will need to see the MCU's datasheet for the full usable voltage range.